# How to run Xcode tests with yml?

Tags: xcode, yaml, github-actions, xctest

It seems like it should be pretty simple, I just want to trigger a build and unit tests to be executed every time a developer pushes to their fork.  GithubActions.

I’m creating a macOS app.

Here is what I'm trying.  It doesn't work.

```
name: Smoke Test CI

 on: [push, merge]

 jobs:
   build:

     runs-on: macOS-latest

     steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v1
     - name: Execute full install
     - name: Xcodebuild Action
       uses: sersoft-gmbh/xcodebuild-action@v1.3
```

Comment: For which CI system?

Comment: @JonReid GitHub Actions